# Is it faster to do bitwise inside an OpenGL shader or beforehand in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, bit-manipulation, shader

I am unsure whether I should and perform bitwise operations and division inside an OpenGL fragment shader, or before running the shader (calculate in C++ and pass as uniform). What I'm actually doing is converting a hex int representing an RGB value into a color that can be used for drawing in OpenGL. Which would usually be faster [on most systems]?

Comment: Is the colour a per-vertex attribute, or are you passing in a texture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a single value calculated per draw call, then do it in C++.

GPUs are insanely fast, but there's little point in getting them to calculate the same value for millions of vertices or fragments.

However, there's the question of how the data is passed around. If you suspect that there's a difference, then try both approaches and profile them.

Comment: I was just thinking frame-rate, although that's a sledge-hammer approach.

Comment: @geofftnz: Remember that the GLSL compiler may also do optimisations. If you perform a single operation many times it might be rewritten into another operation entirely in some cases. Also, for very cheap instructions the noise in framerate from other factors such as the windowing system might be more significant than the performance impact on the shader.

Comment: @Bartvbl agreed... personally I'd probably just do it in the shader just to keep the code in one place. Fast GPUs have made me lazy.